# WCF performance issues - weird slowdown

Tags: performance, wcf

I have a video-processing engine I've written a while ago, a combination of C# and C++, that processes a video file on disk at about 10 frames per second... The C# part of it spawns some threads, and the C++ bits of it instantiate the reader and some video processing routines… There is 1 main thread that is created when the main C# object is created, and this main thread spawns off the C++-based reader thread and the video processing threads. The threading itself is verifiably correct. There are no blocking or deadlock issues in it. The code is/was stable.

Now, if I wrap this whole thing inside a WCF service, and use WCF to set up which file to process, then tell it (the video engine) to “go”, the individual frames process at about the same speed, EXCEPT once in a while, every few seconds, the threads stall out for a while, they look like they're being suspended. It's weird!! doesn't happen when I don't run it through WCF.

This has nothing to do with the WCF calls themselves, because I only make a few initialization calls to the WCF service to get it running, then I don’t call it from WCF any longer!!! The Service itself is “PerSession”, ConcurrencyMode = Multiple, but what’s going on it definitely not a multithreading (locking/blocking) issue. The main WCF interface has a “connect” method, and in it, I create my main C# “background” thread, and from that thread, I create even more C++ based threads.

I put a timer around one of my video processing routines that calls into opencv (seriously) which normally takes 1/10th of a second, and logged it. I’ll get something similar to this:

Time: 100ms

Time: 100ms

Time: 100ms

Time: 100ms

Time: 100ms

Time: 100ms

Time: 100ms

Time: 100ms

Time: 2000ms <--- naughty! doesn't happen when running w/o WCF

Time: 100ms

Time: 100ms

Time: 100ms

Time: 100ms

Time: 100ms

Time: 100ms

There is nothing in particular that makes that frame take longer, it should be 100ms like all the others. Since this timer is around a block of code that is a deep-down openCV routine that I didn’t even write, it seems to me like “somehow”, my thread or the IIS process itself is being suspended, horked, lowered in priority, or just stalled out, because something else is going on.

I’m a WCF newbie, but no dummy to programming and multithreading. I don't know what to look for in WCF, but I'm pretty savvy enough to use tools to look for slowdowns, if only I knew what to look for.

**AGAIN:** it is **NOT** the frequency of WCF CALLS!!! I only call 3 methods then let it rip (by itself)!!! It runs for many minutes w/o another incoming WCF call!

Comment: Is this WCF service being hosted in IIS?  The only thing I can think of is that maybe your code is impacting memory and the GC is being invoked under IIS's request?

Comment: AS @MickyD pointed, if the wcf is hosted in IIS, something can be shutting down the app pool. There's a configuration in app pool that tells IIS when, in some minutes, the app pool can be recycled, you can set the value to zero, to avoid this.

Comment: Yes, hosted within IIS. I forgot that you could even do it without hosting it within IIS! Hah. It's not the app pool being recycled, I'm sure of that.

Comment: Try hosting it in say a console app. If that works then you know it's an IIS config issue, not necessarily restricted to IIS app pools

Comment: I self-hosted the WCF stuff in a console app today, got the same results. But, forgot to mention, this is DEBUG. Debug heap. Debug CLR. When I switched it to Release, found the time discrepancy between non-WCF video engine and WCF-based video engine was (unless I looked wrong) negligible. So... when using the Debug heap, something "odd" is happening to make the threads suspend for one reason or another. I work @ Microsoft, and have been warned by internal developers that the debug heap is "weird" and in debug mode has locks in it that are not documented. Maybe that's it... WIll post more soon.

Comment: Ungh. I feel ill. Now, two days later, I can't get it to repro. In debug, or release. It's as if the problem was never there in the first place. Way to waste 48 hours, Eric...